# How to remove +,% symbols from url and fetch it in form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bellow is my URL and [3] is my to address, It differs when user enters different location through form, I just want first word, that is `mysore` ,how can i remove other things?

```
skc1/final.html?date=12-04-
2017&time=2&from=Bangalore%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&to=Mysore+division%2C+
Karnataka%2C+India&distance=150+km
```

I am using this ,but it should be changed everytime if i enter different location.

```
window.dest_value = dest_value.replace("%2C+Karnataka%2C+India","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode them:

```js
var url = "skc1/final.html?date=12-04-2017&time=2&from=Bangalore%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&to=Mysore+division%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&distance=150+km";

url = decodeURIComponent(url);

document.body.textContent = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just want first word, That is mysore ,how can i remove other things?

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(to=)(\w+)(?=\+)/` to match `"to="` followed by word characters followed by `"+"` character, call `.pop()` on resulting array

```js
var url = "skc1/final.html?date=12-04-2017&time=2&from=Bangalore%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&to=Mysore+division%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&distance=150+km";
var res = url.match(/(to=)(\w+)(?=\+)/).pop();

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Jai They cannot help themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I got this way to fetch the current URL on this site with the following question:

Get current URL in JavaScript?

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the querystring values separately as -

```js
window.onload
{
 var url = "skc1/final.html?date=12-04 -2017&time=2&from=Bangalore%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&to=Mysore+division%2C+Karnataka%2C+India&distance=150+km";
    var vars = [];
    var hash;
   
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
     console.log(hashes);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```